Alternative for System.Web.Ui.Page in ASP.NET MVC
I have below method in class file and tried to pass data from controller but System.Web.Page what can we use.
public void ExecuteCommand(System.Web.UI.Page page, XmlDocument 
request, DeviceResponseHandler responseHandler, ExceptionHandler 
responseExceptionHandler)  
{
    page.RegisterAsyncTask(new System.Web.UI.PageAsyncTask(          
        (sender, e, cb, extraData) 
            => BeginCommand(request, cb, extraData), (ar) => { 
                  try 
                  { 
                      using (var resp = new DeviceResponse(this, ar)) 
                          responseHandler(resp);      
                  } 
                  catch (Exception ex) 
                  { 
                       responseExceptionHandler(ex); 
                  }   
               }, null, null));  
}

I am using below this command but it throws error. I tried with temo data also but that also not works fine
session.ExecuteCommand(this, doc, (response) =>  {      CmdGetNextGlogResponse cmd_resp = new     CmdGetNextGlogResponse();      switch (cmd_resp.ParseResult(response.Xml))      {          case CommandExeResult.OK:              cmd_resp.Parse(response.Xml);    break;          default:              string aed = "Failed!";              break;      }  }, (ex) => { string aed = ex.Message; }); 


Cannot convert controller to System.Web.Ui.Page

Can anyone suggest how to rectify above issues?

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please format your code to be human-readable and elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

System.Web.UI.Page is Webforms, not MVC. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page?view=netframework-4.8.1

yes @VDWWD but above execute command is in class library, we call that library file in mvc project. In asp web forms we pass this command and works fine but in mvc throw error like  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'WebApplication1.Controllers.DevicesController' to 'System.Web.UI.Page'. Any solution to overcome this, i stuck here.

i changed my asp page to System.web.MvcPage it enters but async task not working . Need help / I tried lot of methods but not working
